# Saving a Pipeline with DecisionTreeModel Spark ML

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-ml

**Context:**

I have a Spark ML pipeline that contains a VectorAssembler, StringIndexer, and a DecisionTreeClassifier. Using this pipeline I am able to successfully fit the model and transform my data frame. I would like to store this model for future use, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Pipeline write will fail on this Pipeline because it contains a stage which does not implement Writable. 
Non-Writable stage: dtc_9c04161ed2d1 of type class org.apache.spark.ml.classification.DecisionTreeClassificationModel
```

**What I have tried**:

```
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(assembler, labelIndexer, dt))
val model = pipeline.fit(dfIndexed)
model.write.overwrite().save("test/model/pipeline")
```

This works properly when I remove the classifier (i.e. dt). Is there a way of saving a DecisionTreeClassifier model?

My data consists of some indexed categorical values that I must map back to their original form (I know this will require using IndexToString). I am using Spark 1.6.

Comment: This deserves a JIRA with a feature requests (if it doesn't exist already). You can always use `mllib` model which is writable and pass data back but I doubt it will be satisfactory solution.

Comment: It's weird, because almost all the models got the `save` method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done as of Spark 1.6. The issue is being tracked [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11888).